# who hold reference to these objects

Tags: windbg, sos

I see that dumpheap -stat command is showing 5 instance of my object. When I run dumpheap -MT , it lists all those 5 instances. In theory there should be only 2 instances. Is there any windbg/sos command to trace who hold the reference to these instances.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use !gcroot on the object figure the root.

Comment: What if I just want to do a shallow search or just show direct references?